# How to store a column value into a variable in Data Flow Task?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, ssis-2012

I have DFT, where I extracting a URL from a table and I need to store that value into a variable.

I am using OLEDB Source to connect to My SQL Server and selecting the required columns.
Then I have Conditional Split which will split the right URL for me.
The right URL flow from a conditional split I have mapped to Script Component.

Below is the C# code I have used:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    this.ReadWriteVariables["User::NextPageLink"].Value = Row.href;
}
```

But when I try to execute I am getting a below error:

> [Script Component [116]] Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ReadWriteVariablesNotAvailableException: The collection of variables locked for read and write access is not available outside of PostExecute.
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with the ReadWriteVariable permission. Did you add your variable to "ReadWriteVariables" field in Script Transformation Editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Script Component variables can only be written to in the `PostExecute` method, as opposed to the `ProcessInputRow`  method.  To update a variable with the value from a column, declare a variable outside of these methods, update the variable in `ProcessInputRow`, and assign this value to an SSIS variable in the `PostExecute` method.  And of course add the SSIS variable in the `ReadWriteVariables` field of the Script Component.  As you may be aware, the `ProcessInputRow` method is called once for each row while `PostExecute` is only executed after all the records have been processed, so if you need to do something with values from multiple rows you'll want to perform this logic within the `ProcessInputRow` method.  Just be aware of the additional overhead that comes with performing whatever actions you're doing for each record that comes through this component.

```
string nextPageLink = null;

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    Variables.NextPageLink = nextPageLink;  
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    nextPageLink = Row.href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @userfl89. 
I have coded similarly to yours but I have used VariableDispenser. Does it really need here?

```
public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    VariableDispenser variableDispenser = (VariableDispenser)this.VariableDispenser;
    variableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::NextPageLink");
    this.ReadWriteVariables["User::NextPageLink"].Value = nextpagelink;

 }

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    nextpagelink = Row.href;
}
```