# SSIS Convert the data type object variables to Datetime variables

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, script-task

Here, I am using the Dataflow task, in that "Recordset Destination" task is used and  Datetime field result is assigned to Variable.

I want to use that result [ maximum date] in the control flow for "execute sql" task as datetime parameter. only one record will as result, was date. I didn't use "foreachloop container".

1. How to convert the data type object result to Datetime result?
2. Provide the code/reference  for the script component to set the value in dataflow task?
3. If we need to use Recordset Destination task. need a script to access the record set value using Script task?

Thank you Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you need the whole recordset for another reason.

1. Right before you load into recordset in your dataflow add a Multicast (allows  the full flow to go in multiple directions)
2. Reconnect to original recordset (this will proceed as it always has now)
3. Add an aggregate and perform the max function on your date column and name it maxDate
4. Add a script component and set the value of maxDate to a variable.

So now you have two paths at the end of your dataflow. One leading to the recordset as it always has and a second that will store the maxDate into a variable.

Comment: I reread your question. Now, I think you only have one record in your dataflow and you want to get that into a variable. Replace the recordset in your dataflow with Step 4 above.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the script component to set the value in dataflow task? Thank you

Comment: I googled this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307643/how-to-store-a-column-value-into-a-variable-in-data-flow-task